# Loaded an XML file response, how do I get the data out of it now?

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

I received this XML data and var_dumped it.

How do I use this now and fetch one of the records from inside? like $this->{product}->name etc.?

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#189 (1) { ["products"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#188 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["total-matched"]=> string(1) "3" ["records-returned"]=> string(1) "3" ["page-number"]=> string(1) "1" } ["product"]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#206 (19) { ["ad-id"]=> string(8) "10581256" ["advertiser-id"]=> string(7) "2466656" ["advertiser-name"]=> string(18) "Everydaysource.com" ["advertiser-category"]=> string(21) "MP3 Accessories>Cases" ["buy-url"]=> string(245) "http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-4107027-10581256?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.everydaysource.com%2Fproduct%2Fsnap-on-case-compatible-with-apple-ipod-touch-4th-gen-colorful-zebra%2Fdapptoucco62%3Fesaffcojudtf120626%3Daf%2Bcj%2Bdapptoucco62&cjsku=DAPPTOUCCO62" ["catalog-id"]=> string(8) "cjo:2691" ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["description"]=> string(57) "Compatible With Apple®:iPod touch® 4th Generation" ["image-url"]=> string(73) "http://cdn1.everydaysource.com/cdn2/110207/fb/28/d2/dapptoucco62_1_es.jpg" ["in-stock"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#98 (0) { } ["isbn"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#99 (0) { } ["manufacturer-name"]=> string(14) "EverydaySource" ["manufacturer-sku"]=> string(12) "DAPPTOUCCO62" ["name"]=> string(69) "Snap-on Case Compatible with Apple iPod Touch 4th Gen,Colorful Zebra" ["price"]=> string(4) "8.99" ["retail-price"]=> string(3) "0.0" ["sale-price"]=> string(3) "0.0" ["sku"]=> string(12) "DAPPTOUCCO62" ["upc"]=> string(12) "628569324674" } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#100 (19) { ["ad-id"]=> string(8) "10402409" ["advertiser-id"]=> string(7) "1636472" ["advertiser-name"]=> string(8) "Eforcity" ["advertiser-category"]=> string(21) "MP3 Accessories>Cases" ["buy-url"]=> string(233) "http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-4107027-10402409?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eforcity.com%2Fsnap-on-case-compatible-with-apple-ipod-touch-4th-gen-colorful-zebra-dapptoucco62.html%3Fefaffcojudtf120626%3Daf%2Bcj%2Bdapptoucco62&cjsku=DAPPTOUCCO62" ["catalog-id"]=> string(8) "cjo:1136" ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["description"]=> string(57) "Compatible With Apple®:iPod touch® 4th Generation" ["image-url"]=> string(68) "http://cdn1.eforcity.com/cdn2/110101/41/86/a3/dapptoucco62_1_efc.jpg" ["in-stock"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#99 (0) { } ["isbn"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#98 (0) { } ["manufacturer-name"]=> string(8) "eForCity" ["manufacturer-sku"]=> string(12) "DAPPTOUCCO62" ["name"]=> string(69) "Snap-on Case Compatible with Apple iPod Touch 4th Gen,Colorful Zebra" ["price"]=> string(4) "7.99" ["retail-price"]=> string(3) "0.0" ["sale-price"]=> string(3) "0.0" ["sku"]=> string(12) "DAPPTOUCCO62" ["upc"]=> string(12) "628569324674" } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#101 (19) { ["ad-id"]=> string(8) "10581247" ["advertiser-id"]=> string(7) "2466659" ["advertiser-name"]=> string(15) "iTrimming Corp." ["advertiser-category"]=> string(21) "MP3 Accessories>Cases" ["buy-url"]=> string(165) "http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-4107027-10581247?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.itrimming.com%2Fdapptoucco62.html%3Fitaffcojudtf120626%3Daf%2Bcj%2Bdapptoucco62&cjsku=DAPPTOUCCO62" ["catalog-id"]=> string(8) "cjo:2690" ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["description"]=> string(57) "Compatible With Apple®:iPod touch® 4th Generation" ["image-url"]=> string(68) "http://cdn1.itrimming.com/cdn2/110301/c9/cc/33/dapptoucco62_1_it.jpg" ["in-stock"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#98 (0) { } ["isbn"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#99 (0) { } ["manufacturer-name"]=> string(9) "iTrimming" ["manufacturer-sku"]=> string(12) "DAPPTOUCCO62" ["name"]=> string(69) "Snap-on Case Compatible with Apple iPod Touch 4th Gen,Colorful Zebra" ["price"]=> string(4) "7.59" ["retail-price"]=> string(3) "0.0" ["sale-price"]=> string(3) "0.0" ["sku"]=> string(12) "DAPPTOUCCO62" ["upc"]=> string(12) "628569324674" } } } }
```

Pastebin of the same : http://pastebin.com/XYN8ysEG

Thank you!

** Edit **

Here is the raw data

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#189 (1) {
  ["products"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#188 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["total-matched"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["records-returned"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["page-number"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["product"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#206 (19) {
        ["ad-id"]=>
        string(8) "10450940"
        ["advertiser-id"]=>
        string(7) "1427863"
        ["advertiser-name"]=>
        string(12) "Bookbyte.com"
        ["advertiser-category"]=>
        string(5) "Books"
        ["buy-url"]=>
        string(151) "http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-4107027-10450940?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bookbyte.com%2Fproduct.aspx%3Fisbn%3D1576751740%26noredirect%3Dtrue&cjsku=13671976"
        ["catalog-id"]=>
        string(8) "cjo:1574"
        ["currency"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["description"]=>
        string(34) "This book is in Like New condition"
        ["image-url"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#77 (0) {
        }
        ["in-stock"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#74 (0) {
        }
        ["isbn"]=>
        string(10) "1576751740"
        ["manufacturer-name"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#75 (0) {
        }
        ["manufacturer-sku"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#72 (0) {
        }
        ["name"]=>
        string(53) "Leadership and Self Deception: Getting Out of the Box"
        ["price"]=>
        string(4) "13.5"
        ["retail-price"]=>
        string(5) "14.95"
        ["sale-price"]=>
        string(3) "0.0"
        ["sku"]=>
        string(8) "13671976"
        ["upc"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#73 (0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#78 (19) {
        ["ad-id"]=>
        string(8) "10450940"
        ["advertiser-id"]=>
        string(7) "1427863"
        ["advertiser-name"]=>
        string(12) "Bookbyte.com"
        ["advertiser-category"]=>
        string(5) "Books"
        ["buy-url"]=>
        string(148) "http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-4107027-10450940?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bookbyte.com%2Fproduct.aspx%3Fisbn%3D1576751740%26noredirect%3Dtrue&cjsku=1084348"
        ["catalog-id"]=>
        string(8) "cjo:1574"
        ["currency"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["description"]=>
        string(41) "This book is in New - Excellent condition"
        ["image-url"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#73 (0) {
        }
        ["in-stock"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#72 (0) {
        }
        ["isbn"]=>
        string(10) "1576751740"
        ["manufacturer-name"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#75 (0) {
        }
        ["manufacturer-sku"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#74 (0) {
        }
        ["name"]=>
        string(53) "Leadership and Self Deception: Getting Out of the Box"
        ["price"]=>
        string(5) "11.21"
        ["retail-price"]=>
        string(5) "14.95"
        ["sale-price"]=>
        string(3) "0.0"
        ["sku"]=>
        string(7) "1084348"
        ["upc"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#77 (0) {
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#79 (19) {
        ["ad-id"]=>
        string(8) "10450940"
        ["advertiser-id"]=>
        string(7) "1427863"
        ["advertiser-name"]=>
        string(12) "Bookbyte.com"
        ["advertiser-category"]=>
        string(5) "Books"
        ["buy-url"]=>
        string(148) "http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-4107027-10450940?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bookbyte.com%2Fproduct.aspx%3Fisbn%3D1576751740%26noredirect%3Dtrue&cjsku=12530742"
        ["catalog-id"]=>
        string(8) "cjo:1574"
        ["currency"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["description"]=>
        string(34) "This book is in Like New condition"
        ["image-url"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#77 (0) {
        }
        ["in-stock"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#74 (0) {
        }
        ["isbn"]=>
        string(10) "1576751740"
        ["manufacturer-name"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#75 (0) {
        }
        ["manufacturer-sku"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#72 (0) {
        }
        ["name"]=>
        string(53) "Leadership and Self Deception: Getting Out of the Box"
        ["price"]=>
        string(5) "29.25"
        ["retail-price"]=>
        string(5) "14.95"
        ["sale-price"]=>
        string(3) "0.0"
        ["sku"]=>
        string(8) "12530742"
        ["upc"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#73 (0) {
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#76 (19) {
        ["ad-id"]=>
        string(8) "10586024"
        ["advertiser-id"]=>
        string(7) "2172304"
        ["advertiser-name"]=>
        string(5) "Chegg"
        ["advertiser-category"]=>
        string(45) "Media > Books > Non-Fiction > Education Books"
        ["buy-url"]=>
        string(116) "http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-4107027-10586024?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2Fdetails%2F1576751740&cjsku=1576751740"
        ["catalog-id"]=>
        string(8) "cjo:2718"
        ["currency"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["description"]=>
        string(584) "The disease of self-deception (acting in ways contrary to what one knows is right) underlies all leadership problems in today&#39;s organizations, according to the premise of this work. However well intentioned they may be, leaders who deceive themselves always end up undermining their own performance.This straightforward book explains how leaders can discover their own self-deceptions and learn how to escape destructive patterns. The authors demonstrate that breaking out of these patterns leads to improved teamwork, commitment, trust, communication, motivation, and leadership."
        ["image-url"]=>
        string(53) "http://c.chegg.com/covers2/10000/15246_1307127219.jpg"
        ["in-stock"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#73 (0) {
        }
        ["isbn"]=>
        string(10) "1576751740"
        ["manufacturer-name"]=>
        string(9) "chegg.com"
        ["manufacturer-sku"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#72 (0) {
        }
        ["name"]=>
        string(29) "Leadership and Self-Deception"
        ["price"]=>
        string(4) "9.99"
        ["retail-price"]=>
        string(5) "15.95"
        ["sale-price"]=>
        string(3) "0.0"
        ["sku"]=>
        string(10) "1576751740"
        ["upc"]=>
        string(13) "9781576751749"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they are Objects (SimpleXMLElement)

```
$result->products->product[0]->name
```

Comment: That worked great, and now if I want to use a foreach statement on it to output several cases? <?php foreach($results->products AS $product){ echo $product->name; } } ?> ?

Comment: no `foreach($results->products->product as $product){ echo $product->name; } }`, because the array is `$results->products->product`

Comment: Sorry to bug one more itme, for some reason price, and name work, but buy-url won't work? Is there a different naming convention for stuff with dashes (-) in between?  because it won't work for image url either.

Comment: nvm got it $product -> {'buy-url'};